# I can not put file value in my formBuilder because of "Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement'"

Tags: angular

I am trying to make formgroup to register with an image.
here is my template for fileuploader:

```
<label for="file-loader" class="float-right">
  <img src="assets/images/robot-02-icon.png" alt="robot" *ngIf="!imgURL">
  <img [src]="imgURL" height="200" *ngIf="imgURL">
</label>
<input type="file" formControlName="photo_id" id="file-loader" (change)="readURL($event)">
```

> here is my readURL function():

```
  readURL(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();
    this.imagePath = event.target.files;
    this.registerForm.patchValue({
      photo_id: event.target.files[0]
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = ( ) => {
      this.imgURL = reader.result;
      console.log(this.imgURL = reader.result);
      this.registerForm.patchValue({
        photo_id: reader.result
      });
    };
  }
```

> my formbuilder is like this:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  password: ['', Validators.required],
  photo_id: [''],
});
```

and when I am trying to submit the form I receive this message in my console:

> > SingupComponent.html:10 ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my opinion you should not have a formControlName in your input file. The error shows up because when you read up your selected file your are getting a data as follow in your FormControl:

```
C:\\some_directory\\file.png
```

and when the FileReader ends up the process, the result is as follow:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCADIAMgDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQAAAAcBAQEAAAA...
```

then you are trying tu put that data into the `FormControl` again doing a `patchValue` and is for that reason the error thrown, because you are patching data incompatible with the input file interface. I recommend you remove the `formControlName` from the input file and everything should work with the `(change)`.

On the other hand, you are being redundant because you are catching the file selected in two sides, in this case the `FormControl` and `(change)`, in this last you are transforming the data and overriding it in the FormControl with other format. I hope I were clear -.-